# Swift 3.0 closure expression: what if the variadic parameters not at the last place in the parameters list?

Tags: swift, closures, swift3, variadic

### Update at 2016.09.19

There is a tricky, indirect way to use variadic parameters before some other parameters in closure expression parameters list, haha

```
let testClosure = { (scores: Int...) -> (_ name: String) -> String in
    return { name in
        return "Happy"
    }
}
let k = testClosure(1, 2, 3)("John")
```

And I found some related issues in bugs.swift.org:
[SR-2475](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2475?jql=text%20~%20%22closure%20variadic%22)
[SR-494](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-494)

### Original Post

According to the [document of Swift 3.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94), for a closure expression, "variadic parameters can be used if you name the variadic parameter"(see Closure Expresssion Syntax part). But for Swift 2.x, the description is "Variadic parameters can be used if you name the variadic parameter **and place it last in the parameter list**", the border part has been removed in Swift 3.0 document, is it means variadic parameter can be a argument of closure expression even it is not at the last place? If so, why the codes below can't compile successfully?

```
let testClosure = { (scores: Int..., name: String) -> String in
    return "Happy"
}
let k = testClosure(1, 2, 3, "John") // Missing argument for parameter #2 in call
```

If the argument label can be used in the call, I think the compiler can compile the code above successfully, but in Swift 3.0, closure expression's argument labels are regarded as Extraneous.

Besides, Swift 3.0 document indicates that the parameters in closure expression syntax can be in-out parameters, but Swift 3.0 said that closure expression syntax can use constant parameters, variable parameters, and inout parameters. Why Apple removed descriptions like constant parameters, variable paramters, is it because in Swift 3.0, the parameters can't be `var`?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would say this is a mistake on Apple's (documentation) part w.r.t. closures specifically (removing statement regarding the demand that the variadic parameter should be placed last): since closure parameters cannot have external names, a variadic parameter that precedes a regular one will lead to situations where arguments given will have ambiguous internal parameter matching (e.g. where variadic and following param. both have same type). The same does not hold for functions _given that we use external parameter names_ to yield non-ambiguity in matching arguments to internal parameter names.

Comment: @dfri Thank you! I think this explaination is make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Still in Swift3 variadic arguments have to be the last parameter in the signature, because despite the fact that in your case the last parameter typed as `String` can be deduced, there's some cases where not, because of the infinite expansion of variadic argument:

```
let foo = { (i:Int..., j: Int) -> Int  in
    return j
}
foo(1,2)
```

**...in Swift 3.0, the parameters can't be var?**

`var` params where removed in Swift3 [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md) to avoid confusion with `inout` parameters, because both `var` and `inout` params can be assigned inside function, but just `inout` is reflected back.

```
 func doSomethingWithVar(var i: Int) {
    i = 2 // change visible inside function.
 }

 func doSomethingWithInout(inout i: Int) {
    i = 2 // change reflected back to caller.
 }
```

removing `var` from parameter list, remove the confusion above.

Comment: The first is not true in case of functions (subset of closures), where you may use external parameter names to separate the different arguments. E.g. `func foo(_ scores: Int..., bar: Int) { ... }` may be called as `foo(1, 2, 3, bar: 42)`.

Comment: Thank you @xhamr, but I think the document of Swift 3.0 removed the description about the place of variadic paramter, so the variadic parameter should can be anywhere in the parameter list -- in your code, the closure also accepted by the compiler, which not be accepted is the call of that closure. so the problem happened when the closure be called -- It seems we can't call it successfully. I just want to find a way to call it...

Comment: @Lanford as per my comment above, you need to switch to functions and use external parameter names if you want to be able to use variadic parameters at non-last positions of a parameter list.

Comment: @dfri functions have the property to bind an argument to a named parameter declaration, but closure not, so, variadic will have to be the last in context where you can't name a param, like in closures.

Comment: @xhamr yes this is exactly what I wrote above :) (see also my comment to the question).

Comment: @Lanford the fact that the compiler don't emit an error in the signature is because variadic can be the first param in `functions` like the code of @dfri and still be used in function calls naming the parameter explicitly, but in closure not, because you can't name a closure param at call.

Comment: @dfri thanks. In fact I'm just reading the document of Swift 3.0, and curious about this question.

Comment: @xhamr I think I need to read a post about why they regard the argument label of closure is extraneous...not convenient to me...

Answer (score 0):

Variadic parameter have to be last and according to your situation, you can type this:

```
let testClosure = { (_ name: String, scores: Int...) -> String in
    return "Happy"
}
let k = testClosure("John", 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create a func in Swift 3.0 where the variadic parameter is NOT the last argument. For example...

```
func addButtons(buttons: UIButton..., completion: (() -> ())? = nil)
```

I believe it's because the parameter following the variadic parameter is named, and so the func does not confuse the next named argument with more variadic arguments.

```
addButtons(buttons: button1, button2, button3) {
     //do completion stuff
}
```