# Assign print function to a variable

Tags: swift

I am new to swift programming . How to assign print function to a variable and call via that variable in swift?

```
var myPrint = print
myPrint("calling print function")//This line shows error
```

Second line (`myPrint("calling print function")`) shows this error:

> Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

```
Playground execution failed:

error: TestingPlayground.playground:5:33: error: missing argument for parameter #2 in call
myPrint("calling print function")
                                ^
                                , 

TestingPlayground.playground:4:5: note: 'myPrint' declared here
var myPrint = print
    ^
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Instead of saying "This line shows error", you need to tell us exactly what the error message says. I typed your code into the Swift interpreter and it worked with no errors.

Comment: The error says "Missing argument for parameter #2 in call " when i passed another string "hello" as #2 like myPrint("welcome to swift", "hello") it again showed the same error

Comment: @robmayoff I have just replicated the same issue, with the same code - the question includes all the data needed to replicate it. Updated the question to reflect it.

Comment: I think I typed the wrong thing into the Swift interpreter, because now I can reproduce the error with rajneesh's code.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336134/2976878

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548852/swift-3-0-closure-expression-what-if-the-variadic-parameters-not-at-the-last-pl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've found a known bug (or limitation) of the Swift compiler.

[The built-in `print` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) has three parameters. Parameter #1 is unlabeled and is type `String ...` (variadic). Parameter #2 has label `separator`, is type `String`, and has a default value. Parameter #3 has label `terminator`, is type `String`, and has a default value. Since parameters #2 and #3 have default values, you can call it like `print("hello")`.

Closures (like `myPrint`) cannot use labeled parameters. So `myPrint` takes three unlabeled parameters. Parameter #1 is type `String ...` (variadic). Parameter #2 is type `String`. Parameter #3 is also type `String`. Closure parameters cannot have default values, so `myPrint` requires all three parameters. You cannot call it like `myPrint("hello")`, because you haven't passed anything for parameters #2 and #3 and they do not (and cannot) have default values.

In Swift, a variadic parameter (like parameter #1 of `print` and `myPrint`) consumes **all** arguments until in reaches a label. If you try to call `myPrint("hello", " ", "\n")`, all three arguments will be assigned to parameter #1, and nothing will be assigned to parameters #2 and #3.

Since you cannot have labeled parameters in a closure, there is **no way** to call your `myPrint` closure, because there is no way to pass values for parameters #2 and #3.

This is a known limitation. See [SR-2475](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2475) and [SR-494](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-494).

Answer (score 2):

`print` includes a variadic parameter followed by named parameters with defaults, which means it's hard to use a reference to it this way. The signature for `print` is:

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)
```

So the type of `myPrint` is `(Any..., String, String) -> ()`. This is difficult to call because two more parameters are required after the `Any...` has sucked up all the parameters. Closures don't allow named parameters currently, so getting this to work is difficult at best, impossible at worst.

The way you do this in Swift is to create wrapping closure:

```
let myPrint = { print($0) }
```